# Jquery change text and icon of button

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

Im trying to send the text and fontawesome icon of a button when click before sending an ajax request, but I can, im using method chaining

```
$("#submit").html("Sending...").addClass("btn-warning");
$("#avion").addClass("fas fa-cog fa-spin");
```

However this is not working, the button only changes the text to sending but the font awesome icon is not changing, even if I change the .html method to val or text its not working, What am I doing wrong?
By the way since Im kinda new to coding I would like to know the following
when I declare the Jquery script with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();
```

what happen if I declare the variables before the click function? are they initialized with 0?

https://jsfiddle.net/hwocnmzo/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `.html()` you replace the whole content of the button. Since the icon is a part of such content, it is gone.

You should replace  only the text node. Use

```
$("#submit").addClass("btn-warning")
               .contents().filter(function () {
                       return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
               })[0].nodeValue = "Sending...";
$("#avion").addClass("fas fa-cog fa-spin");
```

About the `var`s, when you declare them without initialization, they get the value `undefined`.

---

### Alternative solution:

You could wrap the button text in a `<span>` tag, and adjust its text instead of having to select the text node. Example:

```html
<button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i id="avion" class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
  <span>Submit<span>
</button>
```

```js
$("#submit").addClass("btn-warning").find('span').text("Sending...");
$("#avion").addClass("fas fa-cog fa-spin");
```

---

## Explanation of the first (text node replacement) solution

This is to explain the first solution, but let's take a look at the second solution's HTML:

```
<button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i id="avion" class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
  <span>Submit<span>
</button>
```

As you can see, the `<button>` element has two **child** elements `<i>` and `<span>`.

Now let's have a look at the original HTML:

```
<button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i id="avion" class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
  Submit
</button>
```

The difference is that there's no `<span>` wrapping the "Submit" text. The thing is, when that happens, the DOM creates something known as "Text Node". It is as if this happened in practice:

```
<button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i id="avion" class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
  <text-node>Submit<text-node>
</button>
```

But that `text-node` tag does not exist in reality. As it does not exist, you can't select it (like you select the `<span>` tag, via `.find("span"), in the alternative solution).

And because it is not a tag, the way to "access" it is getting a hold of the element's contents. Which happens via:

```
var buttonsContents = $("#submit").contents();
```

And then you filter it, keeping in the collection only the parts of the `contents` (called nodes) that are of type text.

```
var nodesOfTypeText = $("#submit").contents().filter(function () {
     return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
});
```

Having that, and since we know that `#submit` has onlye *one* text node, the text node containing the string `Submit`, we access such first node:

```
var textNodeWithSubmitText = nodesOfTypeText[0];
```

And then we change its value:

```
textNodeWithSubmitText.nodeValue = "Sending...";
```

In other words, the code:

```
$("#submit").contents().filter(function () {
                       return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
               })[0].nodeValue = "Sending...";
```

Would be, if expanded:

```
var buttonsContents = $("#submit").contents();
var nodesOfTypeText = buttonsContents.filter(function () {
     return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
});
var textNodeWithSubmitText = nodesOfTypeText[0];
textNodeWithSubmitText.nodeValue = "Sending...";
```

And that's it. As a side note, if you are not familiar with the `.filter()` function, I recommend [its official docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: It works but can you explain me? I understand the part of html replacing the whole content of the button but im confused whit the code solution you first put
contents().filter(function () {
                       return this.nodeType == 3;
                   })[0].nodeValue = " Sending...";
then
contents().filter(function () {
                       return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
               })[0].nodeValue = "Sending...";
whats the difference and how the solution works

Comment: `Node.TEXT_NODE` is just a constant with value `3`. I replaced it because it makes the code more readable. About the explanation, I have updated the answer, take a look.

Comment: @acdcjunior do not forgot to `.removeClass("fa-paper-plane")` before you add the new class for Font Awesome.

Comment: @Twisty there doesn't seem to be a need for that: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/hwocnmzo/9/

Comment: @acdcjunior agreed, just good practice. FontAwesome can get confused if there are two classes if it is rendered again for any reason.

Comment: @acdcjunior damm the second solution seems harder than the first one since you seem to be a pro coder whats the best solution? besides how does my code look? I mean validation structure

Comment: Yeah, you say you are kinda new to coding, but it actually is quite good. If you don't mind me suggesting, I would just place the error message `span`(`id="error_mess"`) to the right of the submit button. More of a style kind of thing (I think it would look better for the end user, less of a "button jump"). But otherwise all looks good!

Comment: one final question, how can I return the button to its original state I mean with the paper plane and the btn-primary class? by adding classes? or there ir some other way?

Comment: Perhaps if you want to restore, a better option would be to declare two buttons and have one hidden. Then show/hide one another accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/hwocnmzo/22/

Answer (score 2):

You're removing `<i>` when you use `.html()`. Try this:

```
beforeSend: function() {
  $("#submit").html("<i id='avion' class='fas fa-cog fa-spin'></i> Sending...").addClass("btn-warning");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0rvpxwp4/

Good Luck!